# How do I get the vocabulary of a term inside an "article" type content type?

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type tagged with various vocabularies. Each vocabulary has terms which I want to style with particular colours based on the vocabulary. For example, say I have a "Fruits" vocab which has term 'apple' and 'banana' and a "veggies" vocab with 'onion' and 'carrot'. I want to colour the apple and banana tags RED and the onion and carrot tags BLUE *in same node. Say I've a content type "article" which is tagged with apple from the fruits vocab and carrot from the veggies vocab. 'apple' should have a RED background and 'carrot' and BLUE background. Another content node has apple and banana for tags and they should both be RED.

I've found the following code, but it only works when the page I am viewing is the "apple" page - that is, I'm reading the page for the vocab term apple, NOT a content type tagged with apple. It DOESN'T work for tags in other content types and I'm failing miserably to find the right code.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field__entity_reference(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical') {
  // load the term entity and get the data from there
  $term = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('taxonomy_term');
  $variables['vocab'] = $term->bundle();
  }
}
```

My theme has custom twig files for field--entity-reference.html.twig

and I'm trying to use the preprocess function above. Nothing I can find anywhere addresses this; what gives?

Comment: There is a lot missing here. First I don't think is the right hook. You either want node, or field (to loop the field items in either) and based on that, create new variables. Two, you don't need to check the route, this route only returns true if you are looking at the term page itself.

Comment: The field--entity-reference.html.twig *seems* to be correct, because I can work with the individual tags there. for Example:

(begin code)    <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('taxonomy--item') }}>
    <a class="btn-small btn-danger" href="{{ item.content['#url'] }}" role="button">{{ mylabel|striptags }}
    </a>
    </div>
(end code) Soooo, 
"item.content['#url']" DOES get the correct individual terms. Each one gets the url to its own page. But how can I here find each terms parent?

Comment: but i see that the preprocess hook is wrong. thanks

Comment: Some more info. This will get me each tag's uuid --- {{ item.content['#options'].entity.uuid.0.value}}   --- But I cannot seem to get the 'vid' value...which is all i really need.

Comment: After much trial and error THIS WORKS:  ———   {{ item.content['#options'].entity.vid.0.value['target_id'] }}

Comment: And my final code in the field--entity-reference.html.twig file: `{% for item in items %}
        {% set mylabel %}
          {{ item.content }}
        {% endset %}
        {% set myclass %}
          {{ item.content['#options'].entity.vid.0.value['target_id'] }}
        {% endset %}
        {% set myclass = myclass|replace({'_':'-'}) %}
        <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('taxonomy--item') }}>
          <a class="btn-small btn-primary tag-{{ myclass|trim }}" href="{{ item.content['#url'] }}" role="button">{{ mylabel|striptags }}</a>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}`

Comment: Not exactly what I was thinking... but note that that template will affect _all_ entity reference field types.

Comment: @ Kevin But that just means taxonomy terms right? Or is there something else that is an entity reference?

Comment: Any entity reference field type rendered by your theme will use this template - you would have to use the suggestion name that has the field machine name in it to be specific.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you misunderstood. I'm asking does "entity reference" equal "taxonomy term"? Or can entity reference refer to something else, too?

Comment: Entity reference is a field type. That template will match any other entity reference field you will use. You can add more than one Entity Reference type field...

Comment: Yup, I see that now. using the field--entity-reference.html.twig file was messing up entity references in a paragraphs field. So, I've gone for using the field.html.twig file.

Comment: Now that will affect every single field.

Comment: Yeah, I can probably put the code back in field--entity-reference. Why though can't we simply target taxonomy-term.html.twig? *that* would be nice, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You need to look at the twig suggestions in the source output and target the _exact_ thing you want to override. If you override the base templates that means _any field_ or _any entity_ gets overridden with markup it probably does not need. Check the theming documentation.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But nothing is being suggested in between 1) `field--field-resource-topic.html.twig` (too narrow) and 2) `field--entity-reference.html.twig`. All other suggestions are even more narrow or more encompassing. So, it's either go with 2 and catch whether something is a taxonomy term or not or go with 1 and have up to 10 twig templates (one for each vocabulary) that all have essentially the same code. Now core does have a taxonomy-term.html.twig file, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work in this case. I appreciate your continued comments though! They are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone comes along here, I've left the other answer (now below), but have since found a better solution.

Instead of using the `field--entity-reference.html.twig` I'm now using field.html.twig. I suspect that eventually this might lead to an 'include' or 'embed' solution, but I'm not there yet.

For now, since my "tags" will never show labels, I only use this code in the field.html.twig file @ `{% if label_hidden %}`. The code is copied twice (which I don't like and which makes me want to find a different, cleaner solution), once for `{% if multiple %}` and again for if not multiple, since a node may only have one tag, or several.

Here is the code:

```
{% if label_hidden %}
{% if multiple %}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field--items') }}>
  {% for item in items %}
  {% set mylabel %}
      {{ item.content }}
  {% endset %}
  {% set myclass %}
    {{ item.content['#options'].entity.vid.0.value['target_id'] }}
  {% endset %}
  {% set cls %}
  {{ ('field_' ~ myclass)|trim }}
  {% endset %}
  {% set cls = cls|replace({' ':''}) %}
  {% if (field_name|trim == cls|trim ) %}
  {% set myclass = myclass|replace({'_':'-'}) %}
  <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('taxonomy--item') }}>
    <a class="btn-small tag-{{ myclass|trim }}" href="{{ item.content['#url'] }}" role="button">{{ mylabel|striptags }}</a>
  </div>
  {% else %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field--item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% else %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer now. My final code in the field--entity-reference.html.twig file:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% set mylabel %}
    {{ item.content }}
  {% endset %}
  {% set myclass %}
    {{ item.content['#options'].entity.vid.0.value['target_id'] }}
  {% endset %}
  {% set myclass = myclass|replace({'_':'-'}) %}
    <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('taxonomy--item') }}>
      <a class="btn-small btn-primary tag-{{ myclass|trim }}" href="{{ item.content['#url'] }}" role="button">{{ mylabel|striptags }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

HERE is the code needed in a node to access the parent vocabulary of the taxonomy terms in the node. (That is, individual tags on a content type node).

```
item.content['#options'].entity.vid.0.value['target_id']
```

*NOTE: This is on Drupal 8.5.3 and none of my "tags" have more than one parent.*